# excel formula to select column values based on two conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to select the values column values corresponding to 0% and Bravo, so I want the values 0.939958, 0,067266 etc. Could someone help me out to select the values? I have tried this:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH((L2=B2:J2)*(L3=B3:J3);0);B4:B21;C4:C21;D4:D21;E4:E21;F4:F21;G4:G21;H4:H21;I4:I21;J4:J21)
```

But this did not work..

Kind regards.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `INDEX` and add two `MATCH`es together:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$J$21,0,MATCH(0%,$B$2:$J$2)+MATCH("Bravo",$B$3:$D$3,0)-1)
```

This works because the `Arizona`,`Bravo`,`Charlie` are a repeating pattern.  So the first Match returns the first starting place 1,4,7 and then the second returns either 1,2,3.  We add them together and subtract one to return the correct column.

The `0` in the second criterion of the `INDEX` tells the `INDEX` to return the full column.  You can then decide what row you want by replacing that with the relative row number desired

You can then change the `0%` and `"Bravo"` to whatever you want.

Your local settings may require the replacement of `,` with `;`.

Comment: That is a lot of updates Mr. Craner!

Comment: @ForwardEd wanted to get the formula out, then explain how it works.  Trying to answer the follow up questions before they are made. I am also bookmarking this for future duplicates.

Comment: Well one of your updates answered one of my questions so I appreciated them.  Just made the initial read very "interupted"

Answer (score 3):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `K3`:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A3:I12,A2:I2=K2),0,1+K1*2)
```

Note that I just used `RANDARRAY()` to fill the matrix with sample data.